# Angular FullStack Two instances same project

Tags: angularjs, express, nodes

I use the [angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) for my project and for testing purpose I would like to run my project on two different browser windows. 
The problem is that I got the same input for each text field on both browsers simultaneously. 
For example: 
On the login page, if I type my email address on one browser it will appear on the login email field in the other browser.
Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project uses browserSync.
When your project is opened using localhost:3000, you should browse to localhost:3001 that will give you a BrowserSync configuration page.

Under Sync Options on that page you can disbable what to sync.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes it's due to that. 3001 is not effective in the generator I use and for the moment I don't have a clue on the way to access browserSync UI to setup correctly this plugin.

Comment: Ok found it in server/express.js //  in : browserSync.init I add this small part
     `
      ui: {
      port: 8080
      }`